# PHP tidy disable repair feature, just indent

Tags: php, indentation, tidy

My code looks like that

```
$markup = ob_get_clean();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'wrap' => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($markup, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
```

There is a big problem: My web php code gets string from database that contains programming materials (like include ,  etc) and tidy gets `<stdio>` as wrong tag, "repairs" (removes it from output) Is there any way to just indent code? I mean not to repair and remove parts of material like `<stdio>`??

Comment: Maybe tidy should be the last step in your processing chain (after all the included code ran), not the first.

Comment: Use XHTML and CDATA tags to prevent tidy from seeing those non-tags as tags?

Comment: *You* are telling the browser (and Tidy) that `<stdio>` is actually a HTML tag - while it is not. Learn how to properly encode text to be used the way you like it. But do not start fixing the problem at the wrong end.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @FrankFarmer tidy class removes programming content parts like <stdio> .. (inside brackets) I want to prevent it. The question is how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [htmspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) functions may help you.

Comment: `htmlspecialhars()` is used when you want to display HTML special chars in an html doc. It escapes HTML reserved chars like `<` and `>` to `&gt;` and `&lt;` so they won't be parsed as HTML (or better to say they will be substituted for code that can be parsed as the corresponding text characters, instead of code). `htmlspecialhars_decode()` does the opposite, so you can figure that out :)